# How to check user name for bad words with PurgoMalum

Tags: javascript

I ask user name and want to make assword filter with pure javascript:
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

The current nasty words limiter is too hard to maintain manually. What would be the best method to call over http to some bad word filter e.g.  http://www.purgomalum.com/service/xml?text=jack ass

This URL returns the valid output "jack"  only

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        person = httpGet    ('https://www.purgomalum.com/service/plain?text='+person);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the framework you are using, you need to make a request to https://www.purgomalum.com/service/json?text=person

then use the response.result to display the value.

See documentation on [purgomalum](http://www.purgomalum.com/)

Comment: Its pure javascript only

Comment: jquery is ok solution